# Google font is displaying default font

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to use a google font but after importing and changing font family, it only changes the font to the default cursive font. When I remove the 'font-family' the text reverts, so it's obviously affecting the correct section of my code.

This is the font I am looking at https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=Weather-App&preview.text_type=custom&selection.family=Concert+One&vfonly=true&query=cinz.

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap");
.title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems for me that you forgot to add the class to your html tag .

I tried your css out and it works perfectly

example

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel&display=swap");
.title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="title"> Hello world!!</p>
```

Comment: you're right, I had a <p> tag inside of a <div> called 'title. As a child of the div, i thought the properties would transfer onto the <p> tag though. Does it not work like that?

Comment: Try to read more about inheritance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance